# TextCrawler Regex Delete everything and keep a specific

Tags: regex, text, web-crawler

I have a large text file that I wanted to remove everything except some specific that meaningful.

In each line of the text file it will include: `junk_data_user_id=xyzabc123456&=_esjunk_data`

some time it will be `junk_data_user_id=abcxyz123456`

All i want is to keep `user_id=xyzabc123456` and remove everything else

I have tried textcrawler with the expression `user_id=.*&`

but the outcome as below

`user_id=abcxyz123456&junkdata`.

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
user_id=[^&]+
```

`[^&]` means 'not &'

If you also want to support searches such as `asd user_id=xyzabc123456 something else`, then use:

```
user_id=\w+
```

Which will match:

'user_id=xyzabc123456'

Here `\w` is a word character

Comment: user_id=[^&]+

that work great so far.

It's possible to clean out the junk, then replace user_id with something else in 1 step process?

Right now I have to save it start it again with find replace.

If it could be done in 1 step it would be great

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but could you not find have the find='user_id=[^&]+', replace='user_id=replacement' where 'replacement' is whatever you want to set the user id to? You may want to add a new question for this.

Comment: sorry for making it so confusing.

with regex user_id=[^&]+

it remove all the junk data and leave user_id="user_id" work great what i ultimately wanted to do it 

replace "user_id=" with a prefix and keep the "user_id"



prefix="user_id"

Answer (score 0):

Limit your expression at everything but numbers and letters:

```
user_id=[0-9a-z]+
```